# Is libsqlite3.tbd the same as libsqlite3.dylib?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I was trying to import libsqlite3 in my project using Xcode7. What I found was libsqlite3.tbd with no icon instead it has a plain white file icon like .h and .m.

Is it the same with libsqlite3.dylib with icon?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Xcode 7, it replaces the use of `.dylib` with `.tbd`. Just use the `.tbd`.

For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help significantly reduce its download size.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/8609#8609

Comment: Now I understand, Thanks!

Comment: __.dylib__ is compiled binary machine code. __.tds__ is a text file with which appears to contain cross-platform module map information.